# rmi java.security.policy access denied

Tags: java, permissions, rmi, server

I am new to RMI topic in java and i wana to create client server applicaiton using RMI,

i followed this tutorial found in this link : [RMI Tutorial using eclipse](http://www.ejbtutorial.com/java-rmi/a-step-by-step-implementation-tutorial-for-java-rmi)

but i am using **netbeans** ,and here  is server code:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.*;   

public class AdditionServer {
       public static void main (String[] argv) {
           try {
               if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
                            {
                                System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
                            }   
                           String policy="file:/home/user/NetBeansProjects/RMIServerSide/security.policy";

                           System.setProperty("java.security.policy",policy);

               Addition Hello = new Addition();

                                    System.out.println("test\n");
                            Registry reg=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

               reg.rebind("rmi://localhost/ABC", Hello);

               System.out.println("Addition Server is ready.");
               }catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println("Addition Server failed: " + e);
                }
           }
}
```

and here security.policy :

```
grant codeBase "/home/user/NetBeansProjects/RMIServerSide/build/classes/" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

then i run the rmiregistry & in the terminal.
then i run the server and here what is the output exactly :

```
Addition Server failed: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.security.policy" "write")
```

Is there something i miss it, like a config for vm or something ???.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have fixed it following  these steps:

1. I have created a policy file, I named it `security.policy`

with the following content

```
grant {
    // Allow everything for now
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

2- Add the following line of code just before binding the remote object to the `rmiregistry`.

`System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:./security.policy");`

Comment: That would have had zero effect unless you also set a security manager, which you would have to set after setting the policy and before the bind, so evidently you didn't. Setting AllPermission with a security manager is pretty pointless anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the policy file *before* you install the `SecurityManager.`

Comment: THanks...i changed the code as u said ,but new Exception has triggered : java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/RMIServerSide/

Comment: You must have removed the `file:` part. Or else it's referring to something inside the policy file, such as the codebase entry, which should be a URL.