# Java System.setSecurityManager() doesn't work well with policy file

Tags: java, security, policy, principal

I expected that, when use System.setSecurityManager() + policy file, it should work.

Here I've got an intelliJ project, with file/directory structure like this:

```
--src
    --main
       --java
           --TestPrinciple.java
       --resources
           --demo.policy
```

And then my code:

```
public class TestPrincipal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "demo.policy");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "demo.config");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
}
```

While the demo.policy is:

```
grant  {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.home", "read";
};
```

It runs with exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.security.policy" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:792)
at TestPrincipal.main(TestPrincipal.java:6)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rmi java.security.policy access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096163/rmi-java-security-policy-access-denied)

Comment: That post didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `demo.policy` doesn't allow the classes permissions to set system properties.

It's also worth noting that the code sets configuration for the security manager after the security manager has been initialised.

The simple solution is to set the security manager last.

Comment: I was confused there for a moment. You've changed the code in the question. Taking both versions together you seem to have a setup that allows the code to set the security manager but if you don't an existing security manager prevents the code setting a system property. Also the change in line number is kind of strange.